# Why do I get "received corrupt message" when connecting to local EventStoreDB?

Tags: rust, eventstoredb

I am developing with Rust a microservice in CQRS DDD pattern and I use Eventstoredb for command service. But when grpc want to connect with Eventstore docker, I have this error:

```
ERROR eventstore::grpc] Error when connecting to https://localhost:2113/: transport error: error trying to connect: received corrupt message
```

I searched a lot of and there is no answer.

Answer (score 3):

Now I found the solution. Connection string has default value for TLS=true, you must manually write TLS=false in the connection string for localhost.

```
 let settings = "esdb://admin:changeit@localhost:2113?tls=false".parse()?;
```

Comment: It's not really the `localhost` issue, it's due to the fact that you running ESDB locally with the `Insecure` option set to `true`. The client uses SSL by default.